Ubuntu 24.04 files and settings glitching in virtualbox
When I try to open files or settings on my Ubuntu VB machine, it glitches and shows me a white window without any content. Here's an image of what it looks like when I try to open the Home folder: 
And here's an image of what it looks like when I try to open settings: 
I did notice that disabling 3D acceleration in Settings >> Display >> Extended Features >> Enable 3D Acceleration fixes this issue, but it makes my Linux environment significantly less smooth. I would like the VM to run smoothly if possible.
Here's an image of some of the relevant settings on my VirtualBox: 
